# Change two dropdown value

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]
 I have created two form, **1.Billing Information 2.Shipping Information**
    when **Billing Information** form fill and click checkbox all value is copy to 
    **Shipping Information**.

```
State Dropdown value is not copying to shipping information Dropdown.

here is my edit.phtml code

<div class="box-left">
                        <div class="entry-edit">
                            <div class="entry-edit-head">
                                <h4 class="icon-head head-account">Billing Information</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fieldset">
                            <table class="form-list" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label">First name</td><td class=""><input type="text" name="billing_first_name" class="input-text" id="billing_first_name"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label">Last name</td><td class=""><input type="text" name="billing_last_name" class="input-text" id="billing_last_name"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="billing_street">Street Address</label></td>
                                        <td class="">
                                            <div class="multi-input">
                                                <input id="billing_street" class="input-text" name="billing_street[0]" value="" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="multi-input">
                                                <input id="billing_street" class="input-text" name="billing_street[1]" value="" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="billing_city">City</label></td>
                                        <td class=""><input id="billing_city" name="billing_city" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="billing_country">Country</label></td>
                                        <td class="">
                                        <?php 
                                                $countryList = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
                                                                ->loadData()
                                                                ->toOptionArray(false);
                                        ?>  
                                        <?php if (count($countryList) > 0): ?>
                                            <select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" onchange="getstate(this.value);" style="width: 57%;">
                                                <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
                                                <?php foreach($countryList as $billing_country): ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $billing_country['value'] ?>">
                                                        <?php echo $billing_country['label'] ?>
                                                    </option>
                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                            </select>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>                                   
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="billing_state">State</label></td>
                                            <td class="">
                                                <div class="input-box" id='statediv'>   
                                                <!--<input id="billing_state" name="billing_state" value="" class="input-text" type="text">-->
                                                    <select name="billing_state" id="billing_state" style="width: 57%;">
                                                        <option value="">--Please Select--</option>                                                 
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="billing_postcode">Zip/Postal Code</label></td>
                                        <td class=""><input id="billing_postcode" name="billing_postcode" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="billing_telephone">Telephone</label></td>
                                        <td class=""><input id="billing_telephone" name="billing_telephone" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>    
                        </div>
                    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1" style="left: 10px; position: relative;" onclick="FillBilling(this.form)">

<div class="box-right">
                        <div class="entry-edit">
                            <div class="entry-edit-head">
            <h4 class="icon-head head-account">Shipping Information</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fieldset">
                            <table class="form-list" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label">First name</td><td class=""><input type="text" name="shipping_first_name" class="input-text" id="shipping_first_name"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label">Last name</td><td class=""><input type="text" name="shipping_last_name" class="input-text" id="shipping_last_name"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="shipping_street">Street Address</label></td>
                                        <td class="">
                                            <div class="multi-input">
                                                <input id="shipping_street" class="input-text" name="shipping_street[0]" value="" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="multi-input">
                                                <input id="shipping_street" class="input-text" name="shipping_street[1]" value="" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="shipping_city">City</label></td>
                                        <td class=""><input id="shipping_city" name="shipping_city" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>                                   
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="shipping_country">Country</label></td>
                                        <td class="">
                                        <?php 
                                                $countryList = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
                                                                ->loadData()
                                                                ->toOptionArray(false);
                                        ?>  
                                        <?php if (count($countryList) > 0): ?>
                                            <select name="shipping_country" id="shipping_country" onchange="getstate1(this.value);" style="width: 57%;">
                                                <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
                                                <?php foreach($countryList as $shipping_country): ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $shipping_country['value'] ?>">
                                                        <?php echo $shipping_country['label'] ?>
                                                    </option>
                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                            </select>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <!--<tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="shipping_state">State</label></td>
                                            <td class="">
                                                <input id="shipping_state" name="shipping_state" value="" class="input-text" type="text">   
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="shipping_state">State</label></td>
                                            <td class="">
                                                <div class="input-box" id="statediv1">  
                                                    <select name="shipping_state" id="shipping_state" style="width: 57%;">
                                                        <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <!--<input id="shipping_state" name="shipping_state" value="" class="input-text" type="text">   -->
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="shipping_postcode">Zip/Postal Code</label></td>
                                        <td class=""><input id="shipping_postcode" name="shipping_postcode" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label"><label for="shipping_telephone">Telephone</label></td>
                                        <td class=""><input id="shipping_telephone" name="shipping_telephone" value="" class="input-text" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>    
                        </div>
                    </div>


<script>
    function FillBilling(f) {

      if(f.chk1.checked == true) {
        f.shipping_first_name.value = f.billing_first_name.value;
        f.shipping_last_name.value = f.billing_last_name.value;
        f.shipping_street[0].value = f.billing_street[0].value;
        f.shipping_street[1].value = f.billing_street[1].value;     
        f.shipping_city.value = f.billing_city.value;
        f.shipping_country.value = f.billing_country.value;
        f.shipping_state.value = f.billing_state.value;
        f.shipping_postcode.value = f.billing_postcode.value;
        f.shipping_telephone.value = f.billing_telephone.value;     
      }else{
        f.shipping_first_name.value = "";
        f.shipping_last_name.value = "";
        f.shipping_street[0].value = "";
        f.shipping_street[1].value = "";        
        f.shipping_city.value = "";
        f.shipping_country.value = "";
        f.shipping_state.value = "";
        f.shipping_postcode.value = "";
        f.shipping_telephone.value = "";
      }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getstate(countryValue) {
    var reloadurl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('subscriptionorder/adminhtml_subscriptionorder/state'); ?>' + 'country/' + countryValue;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: reloadurl, 
        method: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery('#statediv').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function getstate1(countryValue) {
    var reloadurl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('subscriptionorder/adminhtml_subscriptionorder/state1'); ?>' + 'country/' + countryValue;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: reloadurl, 
        method: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery('#statediv1').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>

 ****1. Here is my SubscriptionorderController.php****

public function stateAction() {
            $countrycode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('country');
            $html = "";
            $statearray = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()->addCountryFilter($countrycode)->load();
            if(count($statearray) > 0){
                $html .= "<select name='billing_state' id='billing_state' style='width: 57%;'><option value=''>--Please Select--</option>";
                    foreach ($statearray as $_state) {
                        $html .= "<option value='" . $_state->getName() . "'>" . $_state->getDefaultName() . "</option>";
                    }
                $html .= "</select>";
            } else {
                //$html .= "<input name='billing_state' id='billing_state' title='".Mage::helper('subscriptionorder')->__('State')."' value='' class='input-text' type='text' />";
                $html .= "<select name='billing_state' id='billing_state' style='width: 57%;'><option value=''>--Please Select--</option></select>";
            }
            echo $html;
    }

     public function state1Action() {
            $countrycode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('country');
            $html = "";
            $statearray = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()->addCountryFilter($countrycode)->load();
            if(count($statearray) > 0){
                $html .= "<select name='shipping_state' id='shipping_state' style='width: 57%;'><option value=''>--Please Select--</option>";
                    foreach ($statearray as $_state) {
                        $html .= "<option value='" . $_state->getName() . "'>" . $_state->getDefaultName() . "</option>";
                    }
                $html .= "</select>";
            } else {
                //$html .= "<input name='shipping_state' id='shipping_state' title='".Mage::helper('subscriptionorder')->__('State')."' value='' class='input-text' type='text' />";
                $html .= "<select name='shipping_state' id='shipping_state' style='width: 57%;'><option value=''>--Please Select--</option></select>";
            }
            echo $html;
    } 



[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Find updated js code

```
<script>
        function FillBilling(f) {

          if(f.chk1.checked == true) {
            f.shipping_first_name.value = f.billing_first_name.value;
            f.shipping_last_name.value = f.billing_last_name.value;
            f.shipping_street[0].value = f.billing_street[0].value;
            f.shipping_street[1].value = f.billing_street[1].value;     
            f.shipping_city.value = f.billing_city.value;
            f.shipping_country.value = f.billing_country.value;
            f.shipping_postcode.value = f.billing_postcode.value;
            f.shipping_telephone.value = f.billing_telephone.value;     
            getstate1(f.billing_country.value);
            f.shipping_state.value = f.billing_state.value;
          }else{
            f.shipping_first_name.value = "";
            f.shipping_last_name.value = "";
            f.shipping_street[0].value = "";
            f.shipping_street[1].value = "";        
            f.shipping_city.value = "";
            f.shipping_country.value = "";
            f.shipping_state.value = "";
            f.shipping_postcode.value = "";
            f.shipping_telephone.value = "";
          }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getstate(countryValue) {
        var reloadurl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('subscriptionorder/adminhtml_subscriptionorder/state'); ?>' + 'country/' + countryValue;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: reloadurl, 
            method: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery('#statediv').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function getstate1(countryValue) {
        var reloadurl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('subscriptionorder/adminhtml_subscriptionorder/state'); ?>' + 'country/' + countryValue;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: reloadurl, 
            method: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery('#statediv1').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```